# Independent deployment of separate layers to Azure

Tags: azure, deployment

Lets say I have an application, that is separated into various layers (Presentation, Business, Data Access). How to deploy those layers to Azure independently? The question is about Azure configuration, not about the architecture of application.

Comment: Are you intending on hosting all the three layers on the same physical set of instances?

Comment: I would like to start with hosting all three layers on one instance, but then scale the application in a such way, that each layer has N number of instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An app is usually divided up into various roles, each role being Windows Server 2008 R2 with a defined size and number of instances. You'd typically break your app up into roles for scaling and management purposes. It's often simplest to deploy an app within a single deployment.

On to your scenario: If, say, you want to push up a Web Services layer that lives independently of your app (or maybe it serves multiple apps of yours), then you would put that Web Services layer (in a Web Role, let's say) in its own deployment. You'd need to manage authentication / authorization, since the Web Services would then be using a public endpoint for communication (or you could use Service Bus).

In your example: you could push your Presentation tier (e.g. website) to one deployment with a set of Web Roles, along with supporting services such as Cache. You'd have your Business Layer in another deployment, maybe running with web Services as in my example above. Then your data layer could be SQL Azure (Database-as-a-Service) or maybe a standalone database like MongoDB, running in its own deployment.

Each deployment would have its own project, and you'd deploy and manage each one separately. There's no configuration that spans all deployments.

Comment: ok. lets say I have specified number of instances for each role equal to 1. How to specify that I would like separate instances for each role or one instance for all of them? The reason is that I would like to start with one instance and then to scale up.

Comment: Each role in a deployment has minimum 1 role. It's specified in a configuration, per role. So if you have 5 roles, you'll have minimum 5 instances. This could prove costly for a near-idle system (say, during the night). You can combine functions into a single role if you want. I [blogged](http://www.davidmakogon.com/2011/02/azure-tip-overload-your-web-role-for.html) about this. If you want to actually shut down roles (e.g. you have a worker task that only runs for an hour, then want to drop to 0 instances), you need to put that role in separate deployment, and delete deployment after an hour.