# Deployment of separate layers to Azure

Tags: azure, deployment

Let's say I have 3 instances in the Azure. Each is running separate layer of the application, as I described in this question [Independent deployment of separate layers to Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136354/independent-deployment-of-separate-layers-to-azure). For independent deployment of each layer (read Role) a separate Azure deployment project is created. The question is, what instance will be replaced, when I will be deploying, for example business layer? Can I be sure that the instances with UI and Data Access will stay untouched? How the instance to be replaced is found, based on name of the role?

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, you have 3 layers, each hosted in a different windows azure role (not instance). If you have each role in a seperate deployment (seperate hosted services), then when you deploy, you are only going to be upgrading that layer. The other layers will not be impacted.

However if there are any signature differences, a dependent layer may break if the service its trying to call changes. Its for this reason that you want t omake sure any services support versioning and are always backwards compatible at least one version.

I've created [a quick blog post with some screen shots of doing a single role upgrade](http://brentdacodemonkey.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/partial-service-upgrades/). Note that the silverlight portal issued an exception for me while doing this and I've reported that error and will update the blog post if we find out what it was about.

**Updated:** There is bug in the silverlight management portal that currently prevents the performance of a single role upgrade. The Windows Azure team is aware of this and will be addressing it in a future update. No ETA for that update at this time. However, you can still perform the single role update/upgrade via the management API.

Comment: these role can be in the same hosted service? what is the principle of finding instances that belong to specific layer? is it name of the role?

Comment: Yes, you can host the roles in the same service. If you use RoleEnvironment, you can iterate through the roles and their specific instances. But this isn't really for a service upgrade, more for internal discovery and direct connectivity. Using a manual upgrade, you can actully have single deployment package for the service, but only upgrade specific role (I think, never tried it).

Comment: I'll try to shave out some time tonight to do a blog on the role upgrade for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

As Brent said, it is definitely possible to do a Single Role upgrade. It used to be that if you made any changes to the ServiceDefinition (change VM size, added new Config settings, updated Role Name or changed the instance count from the service definition that is currently deployed) when you upgraded that role, Azure Fabric Controller would not allow you to do in-place upgrade. Now, that is also possible. So you can do an in-place upgrade on Role and bump up the VM size. As always, you at least want to have 2 instances to ensure that you don't experience any downtime.

Ranjith 
http://www.opstera.com